# Create a TypeScript generic type that extends another generic type

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am trying to create a Svelte component that displays hierarchical data.  This component, named for now `HierarchicalBar` renders itself by using the data tree provided.  The data tree provided looks like this:

```js
export type NodeItem<T extends NodeItem<T>> = {
    id: number;
    text: string;
    nodes?: T[]
};
```

This type is used to type the `nodes` prop:

```html
<script lang="ts" generics="TNode extends NodeItem<TNode>">
    export let nodes: TNode[];
    ...
</script>
```

This is so the correct item type shows up in the variable inside the slot:

```html
{#each nodes as node (node.id)}
    ...
    <slot {node} />
    ...
{/each}
```

This part works fine.

Now I want to specialize `HierarchicalBar` to produce menu bars.   So I create a new component named `MenuToolbar`.  For this component, I would like to repeat the pattern above, with one addition:  The type of hierarchical data must comply with `NodeItem<T>` because `MenuToolbar` will use `HierarchicalBar`.

This type I cannot produce, so I cannot show and is the objective of this question.

Expected result:  A `MenuItem` TS type that extends NodeItem and is meant itself to be extended just like `NodeItem<T>`.

Let me know if I should explain anything else.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `type MenuItem<T extends MenuItem<T>> = NodeItem<T>` what you are looking for?

Comment: Hello, @baterja.  I think not.  I just posted a solution.  I don't know if this clarifies any doubts you might have.  Also, I don't know if this is a quality solution.

Answer (score 2):

OK, after some more serious testing and development, I think I came up with a solution. It seems to provide all necessary features.

### Situation

First and foremost, I would like to make people reading this aware of something that was affecting me. I am trying to create a hierarchical component. This means the component will be recursive. This means in Svelte, using `<svelte:self>`.

Because I wanted this component to be the barebones logic for more specialized components, slotting the contents is a must. This is where a very relevant problem comes up.

I opened [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/2312) to describe things. It has a link to issue #1852 that explains the issue: If you create a slot inside `<svelte:self>`, then type inference doesn't work. When I wrote this question up, I was unaware of this which of course was part of my pain. I was losing Intellisense because of this that led me to think my typings were very wrong.

### Solution

The GitHub issue shows it, but I reproduce here. Note the use of the `$$Slots` interface to overcome the type inference bug. `$$Slots` is the interim solution until further notice.

This is the base hierarchical component:

```html
<script lang="ts" context="module">
  export type NodeItem<T extends NodeItem<T>> = {
    id: number;
    text: string;
    nodes?: T[];
  }
</script>

<script lang="ts" generics="TItem extends NodeItem<TItem>">
  export let nodes: TItem[];
  // $$Slots is needed due to bug #1852.
  interface $$Slots {
    default: {
      node: TItem
    }
  };
</script>

<ul>
  {#each nodes as node (node.id)}
    <li>
      <slot {node}>
        <span>{node.text}</span>
      </slot>
      {#if (node?.nodes?.length ?? 0) > 0}
        <svelte:self nodes={node.nodes} let:node={subNode}>
          <slot node={subNode}>
              <span>{subNode.text}</span>
          </slot>
        </svelte:self>
      {/if}
    </li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

This is a derived component that adds one property requirement to the data objects, and renders anchor tags instead of span's:

```html
<script lang="ts" context="module">
    export interface DerNodeItem<T extends DerNodeItem<T>> extends NodeItem<T> {
        href: string;
    };
</script>

<script lang="ts" generics="TItem extends DerNodeItem<TItem>">
    import BaseHierarchy, { type NodeItem } from "./BaseHierarchy.svelte";

    interface $$Slots {
        default: {
            node: TItem
        }
    };

    export let items: TItem[];
</script>

<BaseHierarchy nodes={items} let:node>
    <slot {node}>
        <a href={node.href}>{node.text}</a>
    </slot>
</BaseHierarchy>
```

This provides correct Intellisense, the derived type (which I called `MenuItem` in the question but in this sample is `DerNodeItem`) can be extended further with properties and said properties will be shown by Intellises, and overall I would say satisfies the core requirements I had.

But as Ray William Johnson would say in his tik toks: "UNTIL..." I want to use the component without having the need to add extra properties. Then I must come up with a type that extends `DerNodeItem` and adds no properties! For example, in the GitHub issue you can see `interface TestData extends NodeItem<TestData> {}`. I had to fabricate this "superflous" type or else I could not type the array variable.