# What's the correct way to type an array of objects whose elements are variations of the type?

Tags: typescript

I am creating a generic sorting module in TypeScript.  One of those that receive an array of data objects, then a list of keys on which to sort and once complete the array will be sorted by the keys specified in this list of keys.

So I start out by doing these 2 types:

```
export type Comparer<T>: (a: T, b: T) => number;

export type SortKey<T> = {
    key: keyof T,
    order: 'ascending' | 'descending',
    comparer: Comparer<T[keyof T]>
};
```

The above, when tested, has a problem.  Let's see an example:

```js
// numberComparer is of type (a: number, b: number) => number
import { numberComparer } from 'somewhere';

type Person = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
};

const sortKey: SortKey<Person> = {
    key: 'id',
    order: 'ascending',
    comparer: numberComparer
};
```

This shows a TS error:  The `comparer` property is of type `Comparer<string | number>`, but `numberComparer` is not.  This happens because the type cannot infer that, because the value of `key` is `'id'`, then it will be comparing numbers because `id` is a numeric field.

So v2 of the type:

```
export type SortKey<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
    key: K,
    order: 'ascending' | 'descending',
    comparer: Comparer<T[K]>
};
```

With this version, the example would work if we explicitly specify `K`.  Personally, I think TS should be able to infer it, but whatever:

```js
const sortKey: SortKey<Person, 'id'> = {
    key: 'id',
    order: 'ascending',
    comparer: numberComparer
};
```

The error is now gone.  However, we face another problem.  The generic `sort` function looks like this:

```js
export function sort<T>(data: T[], keys: SortKey<T>[]);
```

Writing the body of the function yields no errors, so that works for the body of the function.  However, the *consumer* of the function cannot do something like this:

```js
const myKeys: SortKey<Person>[] = [
    {
        key: 'id',
        order: 'descending',
        comparer: numberComparer
    },
    {
        key: 'name',
        order: 'ascending',
        comparer: stringComparer
    }
];
```

The above throws the TS errors seen originally, where the given comparer is for a specific type (number or string), but the `comparer` property accepts all the ranges of keys from the `Person` type.

One workaround would be to create a "master" comparer of the required type whose implementation would type-check the parameters and then call the specific comparer accordingly.  Very ugly.

So, my fellow Typescripters, any solutions to this?  As always, you have my gratitude.

Comment: • Please test your example code in an IDE and fix any typos, and consider using `declare` instead of `import {} from 'somewhere'` to make it a [mre] others can easily play with. • Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBdObW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hello, jcalz.  Thank you very much for your time and expertise.  Indeed, I believe your solution behaves as I would like it to.  If you could explain how it works, it would be great, or at least a link on where to learn about this feature/trick of creating "all possible types", and then picking one (or that's how I'm interpreting it).

Comment: @jcalz, I also asked [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137587/create-a-typescript-generic-type-that-extends-another-generic-type) some time ago.  If you could have a look, I'd appreciate it.  It is TypeScript within Svelte.

Comment: • I will write up a full answer explaining how it works when I get a chance (although it is now my bedtime so it will have to wait until I wake up, if that's okay).  For now I'll just say the feature/trick is called a "distributive object type" as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). • I don't know anything about svelte so I'm not inclined to delve into that other question unless you can edit it so as not to have such a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `SortKey<T>` to be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `SortKey<T, K>` for every `K` in `keyof T`.  That is, you want `SortKey<T, K>` to *distribute across unions* in `K`.  So that you get this behavior:

```
type SortKeyPerson = SortKey<Person>;
/* type SortKeyPerson = {
    key: "id";
    order: 'ascending' | 'descending';
    comparer: Comparer<number>;
} | {
    key: "name";
    order: 'ascending' | 'descending';
    comparer: Comparer<string>;
} */
```

That means you want to use some union distribution mechanism. There are a few ways to accomplish this. The most straightforward one when the type you want to distribute over is keylike is a so-called *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). This involves making a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T` and then [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with the full key set.  So if you have a type `F<K>` that you want to distribute over unions in `K`, you can write `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]` to produce a distributive version.

For this example it looks like:

```
type SortKey<T> = { [K in keyof T]: {
    key: K,
    order: 'ascending' | 'descending',
    comparer: Comparer<T[K]>
} }[keyof T]
```

Which you can verify gives you the union type shown above.  Now your examples work as desired:

```
const myKeys: SortKey<Person>[] = [
    {
        key: 'id',
        order: 'descending',
        comparer: numberComparer
    },
    {
        key: 'name',
        order: 'ascending',
        comparer: stringComparer
    }
];
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAQwE4VQHgCoD4oC8UAFMgFxTYA0UARhdgJSH4B2ArgrRgNwBQfUJCgBlOKmABpCCBz4iAbygBtSVACWrKAGsZcAGaUAuhQV8AkLpAVJVC+IAmGCgHJkAZwDGEVg80BzFygAHygXJy8fP1ZAu3NPRBR0VAp4JDQMHFUjXD4AXyg85SsDYwEhaDEJaRAABQx3OC0iKqkZTHrURtZcfgB6ACooCtFxNrqGpsIoMyg5nRkKACJ1ByX+eahHZzCPb18AoNDwiEiDmJcN+YT05NTEjKwOLgxe-JCZvk2rZdZkBAg6y+822KV2Z2igQ+JwhhyucxuSR2aSRWHcwFQATeBQGfQETk8ABsMlAEqx0VBntxUCjHvdbpkqa9+ATiehSU0KejMTFaXdYA9kphuVj+IJwNBOt1pmZzKsKEzUPxzH8ARQRTF+HkxWSKQgQDV3BRWjUOpMesojNNlMC5rNNvMfmFVi47A6QagnGCYftIa7bQ7EXTKZxqXyMAG8m75vb3U6XKqIP73XNQa49lFDtH3UH+Rr-OHUJG+EYeEA)