# SortKey<> type doesn't work, despite individual types used by it work just fine

Tags: typescript

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78173887/whats-the-correct-way-to-type-an-array-of-objects-whose-elements-are-variations/78175458#78175458) about TypeScript is what started the topic on this one.  In that previous question, I wanted to create a generic `sort()` method that would work with an array of sort keys, defined by the `SortKey` type you'll see there (and here, I suppose).  The result obtained in said previous question works only for direct properties of the type.

Now I wanted to progress this, and see if I could make it recursive so I could specify keys on nested objects.  This is the work I have:

```js
type Comparer<T> = (a: T, b: T) => number;

type KeyPath<T, TParentKey = undefined> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? (TParentKey extends undefined ? `${K}` : `${TParentKey & string}.${K}`) : never;
}[keyof T]
    | {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? K extends string ? KeyPath<T[K], TParentKey extends undefined ? `${K}` : `${TParentKey & string}.${K}`> : never : never;
}[keyof T]
;

type ValueAtPath<T, Path> = Path extends keyof T
    ? T[Path]
    : Path extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
    ? Key extends keyof T
        ? ValueAtPath<T[Key], Rest>
        : never
    : never;

type Getter<T, K extends string> = (model: T, key: K) => ValueAtPath<T,K>;

// This type is not working and is the subject for this question:
type SortKey<TModel> = {
    [K in KeyPath<TModel>]: {
        key: K;
        order: 'asc' | 'desc';
        getter: Getter<TModel, K>;
        comparer: Comparer<ValueAtPath<TModel, K>>;
    }
}[KeyPath<TModel>];
```

Now, how come I know the "individual types" used inside `SortKey` work?  Like this:

```js
// Let's define a couple of data models.
type User = {
    id: number;
    name: {
        first: string;
        last: string;
    };
    emails?: string[];
    isActive: boolean;
    type: 'customer' | 'support'
};

type Domain = {
    id: number;
    value: string;
    user: User;
};

// Now let's start testing the TS types.
type TestKey = KeyPath<Domain>;

// Visual Studio Code shows in Intellisense the following for the above type:
type TestKey = "id" | "value" | "user" | KeyPath<User, "user">

// Although unsure why it did not expand the recursion, Intellisense fully works on a variable:
const k: TestKey = 'user.name'; // <-- See picture 1.

// This also seems OK as per the Intellisense tooltip:
type TestValue = ValueAtPath<Domain, 'user.name.last'>;
// The tooltip reads it is string, which is the data  type of the `last` nested property:
type TestValue = string

// Now testing Comparer:
const comp: Comparer<ValueAtPath<Domain, 'user.name'>> = (a, b) => 0;
// Intellisense shows:
const comp: Comparer<{
    first: string;
    last: string;
}>

// Finally, testing Getter:
const getter: Getter<Domain, 'user.name.first'> = m => m.user.name.first;
// Intellisense works perfectly on the parameter variable "m".
```

[image: Picture 1: 100% of all keys in Domain]

Ok, so one would think that, by extension, `type DomainSortKey = SortKey<Domain>` would work.  Well, it doesn't.  TypeScript says that `DomainSortKey === unknown`.

The question of the million dollars is:  What in the Jebus happened??

Comment: • Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) • You say "one would think that ... would work". What is "work" here, what exact type are you expecting to see? It would be great if you could give some example input/output for what you expect `SortKey` to produce, because as far as I can tell, your code shows a bunch of types that all build up to it not working. Is your question really "why doesn't my failed attempt work" and *not* "how should I write this"?

Comment: Is it as simple as your `KeyPath` sometimes produces `undefined` because your mapped types don't remove it if it shows up and you can fix it with `-?` modifier as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N78Rqm)? If that's it, I can write up an answer. If not, then I'll need more information about exactly what you're expecting, as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Hello.  I have tested the `-?` modifier as shown in the playground you provided.  It appears to behave.  Aside the fact that I don't know this modifier (and therefore will appreciate a link to its documentation or an explanation on it as part of the answer), I don't see where the `undefined` is produced.  Is it because emails is optional?  So any optional property adds `undefined` to the list?  Anyway, in short:  It appears your solution is what I'm after.

Comment: If you could include the explanation of how one `undefined` boicots the entire union generation of the distributed set, will be appreciated.

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance, but it's my bedtime now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ⋯}`, with `in keyof` in there directly, it will be a *homomorphic mapped type* as described in [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218). That means [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) and [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) properties in the input type will become readonly and optional properties in the output type.  Optional properties will always include `undefined` in their domain.

So that means your `KeyPath<T>` type will end up including `undefined` if any of the keys of `T` (or perhaps even subkeys, given the recursion) are optional. You can test the type to see this (it looks like you tried to do this but didn't fully expand the type. One way to do this is to [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `{} | null | undefined`, a type more or less equivalent to [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown)):

```
type TestKey = KeyPath<Domain> & ({} | null | undefined);
//   ^? type TestKey = "id" | "value" | "user" | "user.id" | "user.name" |
//      "user.emails" | "user.isActive" | "user.type" | "user.name.first" | 
//      "user.name.last" | undefined
```

Now, ideally, TypeScript would be smart enough to prevent you from using `undefined` as a key in an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). But sometimes if generics are complicated enough, the compiler fails to see the problem:

```
type Hmm<T> = { [K in keyof T]: K }[keyof T]
type Grr<T> = T[Hmm<T>]; // <-- this should be an error but it's not
type Okay = Grr<{a: string}> // string
type Bad = Grr<{ a?: string }> // unknown
```

The `unknown` is what happens when the compiler is trying to figure out `{a?: string}[undefined]`. Allowing `undefined` to sneak in as a key is a known design limitation, according to [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#56515](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56515#issuecomment-1829898710), because trying to fix it was causing way too much breakage in real world code. So they allow it, and recommend that if you're writing a type function to extract keys, you should perform the following fix:

---

The recommended fix here is to use the `-?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to make keys required in the mapping and to prevent `undefined` from being included in the domain. (The `-?` modifier is used in the definition of [the `Required<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype)):

```
type KeyPath<T, TParentKey = undefined> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string ? (
    //          ^^
    TParentKey extends undefined ? `${K}` : `${TParentKey & string}.${K}`
  ) : never; }[keyof T]
  | {
    [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends object ? (
      //          ^^
      K extends string ? KeyPath<
        T[K], TParentKey extends undefined ? `${K}` : `${TParentKey & string}.${K}`
      > : never
    ) : never;
  }[keyof T];
```

which removes `undefined` from the list of keys:

```
type TestKey = KeyPath<Domain> & ({} | null | undefined);
//   ^? type TestKey = "id" | "value" | "user" | "user.id" | "user.name" |
//      "user.emails" | "user.isActive" | "user.type" | "user.name.first" | 
//      "user.name.last"
```

which unbreaks `SortKey`:

```
type DomainSortKey = SortKey<Domain>;
/* type DomainSortKey = {
    key: "id";
    order: 'asc' | 'desc';
    getter: Getter<Domain, "id">;
    comparer: Comparer<number>;
} | {
    key: "value";
    order: 'asc' | 'desc';
    getter: Getter<Domain, "value">;
    comparer: Comparer<...>;
} | ... 7 more ... | {
    ...;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAQwE4VQHgCoD4oC8UAFMgFxTYA0UARhdgJSH4B2ArgrRgNwBQfVsgQQAzigDG0APKoAlgHMoAbz5QooSFADSEEAAVkwABY4a2Q+lbBdIQlHasAJhABmc1hCf4iq9eoBtbSgPKABrPThXSgBdCmCIAA9gCGdRKFFgeVYlAH4SCzRUmz0oJJS0h2c3Dy8ofIADABJlbQBfBqgKZuVCqxK7ADIMrI8FNoA6FvaG5gpPADdeNSg2gIiQKNiV9QAfFR3-IJDWcMjo7DjKIJiy5NSndLhaACsICWB6nTuKx5HsvI6PSGEw4G7mSzFWw-B7pRwudyeJxfHozLpQHp9KGlYaZAGTaYdfDzCBLVDoxbLfyrdbnbbU-grAD0TKgADk4AB3KAAGwgwAA5OlMmhPilMmMNMZoNgAMoacBiCYrTQysQDey2EGmAAiiGQHnww2IyjaUH2HB5PPNVQRtScjH46hZ-gAevlVZR1bYAIz2ABEcic-pt-oWyB57AgIf2-vYogwMagcYTqAmQaTKYwEyEIhjzNZ1OT8ezEAQBp5okzJbTclEAEEPnIltXUxNVa3s7mIBN3KhMkmC0Xi23uxMecgBzb4TUkXw2gJPQAJBAIHA+FRQY6hDZbS7xGm7i4xPiegDiqCweHs2ACK7XeBiPCgLswAFo31K6xljHB2DzkW4KBkFODBUDgclaHYT45EFdJWDgYBT0VKBpDCZA7CIC8sGUYCKDxSU2nwF0CJyZCtAAIWQZEsMvTBcOQXJ8NGHJVmI1lHDCBDOVYARyOgLUjFMahKEhaxoSIGdES8Dc-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-TU-YxrHNhGjUN74TuRK0HZKR2zDOmxbZ+2w7P-Lsj9exyH7MAa+Y5I4QKnlABeHgyaoA1EQRBFN4FL34EyAAVAqVu+oEHk1npzDGyYMwy35grKAwspbVyoZLaWhw5bAEhorZWmB0E0BPv6a2-gtZIENhQeA-DdaYA4FwDAGszT7GIXoCgYZJrRnIagAWQsRa0IlmIBh1ImEsKgErZhGB2H4NYJw8+0YeHqD4TrShQjrFYAmA4yRNoHETCgAAdigEjdAUAXEBUOC4-gZosFMiAA)